# Switcher implementation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

I am working on a mid-size application in Javascript. I would like to create a switcher, similar to the OS window switcher. When a UI part becomes active, it should mute all event listeners from other UI parts and give the active UI an exclusive access to the keyboard and mouse input. For example `ctrl+c` on an active panel would copy panel data, while `ctrl+c` on an active canvas would copy a selected shape. Both panel and canvas are contained within a single view.

One way to implement it is to utilize observer pattern giving one observer an exclusive access to mute other observers (the switcher), this would prevent unwanted observers from interfering with the keyboard and mouse input.

This is however an experimental solution, what are the current neat ways to implement this functionality with Javascript?

Comment: I think this is actually more of an HTML/CSS questions -- read up on the CSS property called `pointer-events`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Thanks for the reference, I didn't know about this cool CSS feature. However, this doesn't seem to solve the problem of dispatching the keyboard inupt, as for example, in contrast to input elements one cannot listen for keypress events on a div or canvas, therefore those events must be caught on the window level and dispatched to active observers.

Comment: There's nothing really new in ES6 that would let you do this much different than you would have done it in ES5. If you want to avoid the observer pattern, you should have a look at Functional Reactive Programming however.

Comment: You can listen to key events on a div or canvas. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/dtq8zdov/

Comment: @GökhanKurt This is a wonderful solution! Please post it as an answer as it answers my question, get the bounty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an element to dispatch keyboard events, it must have focus. But, by default some HTML elements like `div` and `canvas` can't have focus on them. If you set `tabIndex` property however, they will also be focusable.

```js
function keypress() {
  console.log("works");
}

document.getElementById("element").focus();
```

```html
<canvas width="10" height="10" tabIndex="0" onkeydown="keypress()" id="element"></canvas>
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you! Bounty in 18 hours due to a delay forced by StackOverflow's reward mechanism...

Comment: Will this be enough for your question?